# How to route multiple passed variables in hyper link to a pretty url using codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am passing multiple variable with hyperlink like id and name (two parameters at time).

Comment: this is the hyperlink in which i am passing parameters
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>editCity?cityid=3&cityname=Mathura">

and when i click on this hyper link url is looking like this
http://www.something.com/editCity?cityid=1&cityname=Mathura

but i want this url in this format only
http://www.something.com/editCity/Mathura

Comment: any solution to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>editCity/3/Mathura">
```

Considering editCity as function in some controller

```
function editCity($id,$name){

    echo $id;// prints 3
    echo $name;// prints Mathura.

}
```

Comment: how to route http://www.something.com/editCity/3/Mathura to http://www.something.com/editCity/Mathura ?

Comment: you shud add controller before function `editCity()`.

Comment: it would look like  something.com/controller/editCity/3/Mathura, or u shud use `routes` if you dont want controller name.

Comment: and i have removed controller's name by routing method but unable to remove the id from this url ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91580/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-upendra-sharma).